# How to integrate frontend with my custom Cordapp?

Tags: web, frontend, blockchain, corda

Hello I am trying to learn some Corda concepts. I have a Cordapp running locally on my system. I want to integrate frontend with it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In Corda, you interact with nodes via RPC. Your frontend server needs to:

- Create an RPC connection to the node
- Use this RPC connection to issue commands and read back data from the node

Here is an [example](https://github.com/corda/spring-webserver/blob/release-V3/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/server/NodeRPCConnection.kt) of creating an RPC connection to the node in Spring:

```
private const val CORDA_USER_NAME = "config.rpc.username"
private const val CORDA_USER_PASSWORD = "config.rpc.password"
private const val CORDA_NODE_HOST = "config.rpc.host"
private const val CORDA_RPC_PORT = "config.rpc.port"

/**
 * Wraps a node RPC proxy.
 *
 * The RPC proxy is configured based on the properties in `application.properties`.
 *
 * @param host The host of the node we are connecting to.
 * @param rpcPort The RPC port of the node we are connecting to.
 * @param username The username for logging into the RPC client.
 * @param password The password for logging into the RPC client.
 * @property proxy The RPC proxy.
 */
@Component
open class NodeRPCConnection(
        @Value("\${$CORDA_NODE_HOST}") private val host: String,
        @Value("\${$CORDA_USER_NAME}") private val username: String,
        @Value("\${$CORDA_USER_PASSWORD}") private val password: String,
        @Value("\${$CORDA_RPC_PORT}") private val rpcPort: Int): AutoCloseable {

    lateinit var rpcConnection: CordaRPCConnection
        private set
    lateinit var proxy: CordaRPCOps
        private set

    @PostConstruct
    fun initialiseNodeRPCConnection() {
            val rpcAddress = NetworkHostAndPort(host, rpcPort)
            val rpcClient = CordaRPCClient(rpcAddress)
            val rpcConnection = rpcClient.start(username, password)
            proxy = rpcConnection.proxy
    }

    @PreDestroy
    override fun close() {
        rpcConnection.notifyServerAndClose()
    }
}
```

And here is an [example](https://github.com/corda/spring-webserver/blob/release-V3/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/server/controllers/StandardController.kt) of using the RPC connection in a Spring controller:

```
/**
 * A CorDapp-agnostic controller that exposes standard endpoints.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/") // The paths for GET and POST requests are relative to this base path.
class StandardController(
        private val rpc: NodeRPCConnection) {

    companion object {
        private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestController::class.java)
    }

    private val proxy = rpc.proxy

    @GetMapping(value = "/status", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
    private fun status() = "200"

    @GetMapping(value = "/servertime", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
    private fun serverTime() = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(proxy.currentNodeTime(), ZoneId.of("UTC")).toString()

    @GetMapping(value = "/addresses", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
    private fun addresses() = proxy.nodeInfo().addresses.toString()

    @GetMapping(value = "/identities", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
    private fun identities() = proxy.nodeInfo().legalIdentities.toString()

    @GetMapping(value = "/platformversion", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
    private fun platformVersion() = proxy.nodeInfo().platformVersion.toString()

    @GetMapping(value = "/peers", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
    private fun peers() = proxy.networkMapSnapshot().flatMap { it.legalIdentities }.toString()

    @GetMapping(value = "/notaries", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
    private fun notaries() = proxy.notaryIdentities().toString()

    @GetMapping(value = "/flows", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
    private fun flows() = proxy.registeredFlows().toString()

    @GetMapping(value = "/states", produces = arrayOf("text/plain"))
    private fun states() = proxy.vaultQueryBy<ContractState>().states.toString()
}
```

You'll note that you need to use Java classes to create a connection to your node. This means that the webserver will need to be written in a JVM language. Alternatively, you can use something like Graal to write the server in a non-JVM language and compile it down to JVM bytecode. There is an example [here](https://github.com/nitesh7sid/cordapp-example-nodejs-server-graalvm).